How to evaluate $(\sin10)^3+(\sin50)^3-(\sin70)^3$
I came across an expression:
$$(\sin10)^3+(\sin50)^3-(\sin70)^3$$
All the angles are in degrees.
Can we calculate it without using calculator by using the trigonometric identities??
I have tried to manipulate this expression such as using sum/difference formulas, but it didn't help.
Any help is appreciated.

Hint: $\sin(3\theta) = 3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta$.

Are the $10,50, \text{ and }70$ degrees?  You should say so.  The default is radians. If I were doing it I would get the angles close to $0$ or $90$ degrees, then use Taylor's series.

$(\sin x)^3$ can be expressed in terms of $\sin 3x$ and $\cos 3x$. Since all the angles in the original expression are multiples of $10°$, all the arguments in the rewritten expression will be multiples of $30°$.

The comment of Sammy Black allows you to convert the original expression into an expression of linear terms $~\sin(a) + \sin(b) + \cdots .~$  At this point, my next (experimental) step, which might well fail to solve the problem is to notice that $~\sin(a+b) + \sin(a - b) = 2\sin(a)\cos(b).~$  I would strive to associate $~(a+b)~$ (et al) with special angles, like $~30^\circ, 45^\circ, 60^\circ.~$  As I say, this approach might well fail.

$$(\sin\frac{\pi}{18})^3+(\sin\frac{5\pi}{18})^3-(\sin\frac{7\pi}{18})^3=-\frac{3}{8}$$

Let $S$ be the sum of $\pm$ cubes of sine values to be computed. We use $4\sin^3 t=3\sin t -\sin (3t)$ for $t$ among $10^\circ$, $50^\circ$, $70^\circ$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
S&:=\sin ^3 10^\circ + \sin ^3 50^\circ - \sin ^3 70^\circ\ ,\\
4S &= 4\sin ^3 10^\circ + 4\sin ^3 50^\circ - 4\sin ^3 70^\circ\\
&=3(\sin 10^\circ + \sin 50^\circ - \sin 70^\circ)\\
&\qquad -\sin 30^\circ
-\underbrace{\sin 150^\circ}_{=\sin 30^\circ}
+\underbrace{\sin 210^\circ}_{=-\sin 30^\circ}
\\
&=-3(\sin 70^\circ-\sin 50^\circ+\sin 30^\circ-\sin 10^\circ)
\\
&=-6(\cos 60^\circ\sin 10^\circ+\cos 20^\circ\sin 10^\circ)
\\
&=-6\sin 10^\circ(\cos (40^\circ+20^\circ)+\cos (40^\circ-20^\circ))
\\
&=-12\sin 10^\circ\cos 20^\circ\cos 40^\circ
\\
&=-\frac 6{\cos 10^\circ}\cdot 
\underbrace{2\sin 10^\circ\cos 10^\circ}_{\sin 20^\circ}
\cdot \cos 20^\circ\cos 40^\circ
\\
&=-\frac 3{\cos 10^\circ}\cdot 
\underbrace{2\sin 20^\circ\cos 20^\circ}_{\sin 40^\circ}
\cdot \cos 40^\circ
\\
&=-\frac 3{2\cos 10^\circ}\cdot 
\underbrace{2\sin 40^\circ\cos 40^\circ}_{\sin 80^\circ}
\\
&=-\frac 32\cdot\frac{\sin80^\circ}{\cos 10^\circ}=-\frac 32\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
From here we obtain the value $S=-3/8$ for the given sum.

$\sin10^\circ$, $\sin50^\circ$ and $-\sin70^\circ=\sin(-70)$ are the roots of $8x^3-6x+1$ (see this).
Therefore, $$8((\sin10^\circ)^3+(\sin50^\circ)^3-(\sin70^\circ)^3)=6((\sin10^\circ)+(\sin50^\circ)-(\sin70^\circ))-3= -3$$ and so the answer is $-3/8$ because the sum of the three roots is zero.

Using the identity $\sin(\alpha)-\sin(\beta)=2\sin\left(\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}2\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2\right)$, we can prove that $\sin(10^{\circ})+\sin(50^{\circ})-\sin(70^{\circ})=0$.
Note that for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$,  $a+b+c=0$ implies $a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$. Hence the expression can be written as follows,
$$\begin{aligned}(\sin10^{\circ})^3+(\sin50^{\circ})^3-(\sin70^{\circ})^3&= -3\sin(10^{\circ})\sin(50^{\circ})\sin(70^{\circ})\\&=-3\cos(20^{\circ})\cos(40^{\circ})\cos(80^{\circ})\end{aligned}$$
Now multiply the expression by $\dfrac{\sin(20^{\circ})}{\sin(20^{\circ})}$. Can you take it from here?
